# SCHTASKS CMD hangs on bat file

Tags: windows, batch-file, scheduled-tasks

When i create a SCHTASK to run launch-min.bat it seems to hang the command prompt but launches no problem when running it manually. Is this caused by start /min and if so are there any workarounds?

**launch.bat**

```
python chrome.py
```

**launch-min.bat**

```
@echo OFF
cd C:\Users\Win\Desktop\
start /min launch.bat
```

**Task**

```
SCHTASKS /CREATE /TN "Launch" /F /TR "C:\Users\Win\Desktop\launch-min.bat" 
/ST 10:00:00 /SC ONCE /SD 05/06/2017 /RU Win
```

Comment: Please share the setup of your scheduled task.  I'm especially curious to see the security options on the "General" tab, but I'd want to see all of the settings.  You can export the task to XML and post the contents if you don't feel like posting screenshots.

Comment: Updated, its just a simple one

Comment: Did you try `/TR "CMD /C C:\Users\Win\Desktop\launch-min.bat"`?